# Error using JPA: Entity is not a known entity type

Tags: jpa, netbeans

I'm getting this this errors when i try to run my java enterprise application, developed using Netbeans 8.1 and GlassFishServer 4

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Object: entity.NewTable[ a=7 ] is not a known entity type.
at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.UnitOfWorkImpl.registerNewObjectForPersist(UnitOfWorkImpl.java:4222)
at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.EntityManagerImpl.persist(EntityManagerImpl.java:496)
at SessBeanPack.provaBean.persist(provaBean.java:30)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
at org.glassfish.ejb.security.application.EJBSecurityManager.runMethod(EJBSecurityManager.java:1081)
at org.glassfish.ejb.security.application.EJBSecurityManager.invoke(EJBSecurityManager.java:1153)
at com.sun.ejb.containers.BaseContainer.invokeBeanMethod(BaseContainer.java:4695)
at com.sun.ejb.EjbInvocation.invokeBeanMethod(EjbInvocation.java:630)
at com.sun.ejb.containers.interceptors.AroundInvokeChainImpl.invokeNext(InterceptorManager.java:822)
at com.sun.ejb.EjbInvocation.proceed(EjbInvocation.java:582)
at org.jboss.weld.ejb.AbstractEJBRequestScopeActivationInterceptor.aroundInvoke(AbstractEJBRequestScopeActivationInterceptor.java:46)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
at com.sun.ejb.containers.interceptors.AroundInvokeInterceptor.intercept(InterceptorManager.java:883)
at com.sun.ejb.containers.interceptors.AroundInvokeChainImpl.invokeNext(InterceptorManager.java:822)
at com.sun.ejb.EjbInvocation.proceed(EjbInvocation.java:582)
at com.sun.ejb.containers.interceptors.SystemInterceptorProxy.doCall(SystemInterceptorProxy.java:163)
at com.sun.ejb.containers.interceptors.SystemInterceptorProxy.aroundInvoke(SystemInterceptorProxy.java:140)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
at com.sun.ejb.containers.interceptors.AroundInvokeInterceptor.intercept(InterceptorManager.java:883)
at com.sun.ejb.containers.interceptors.AroundInvokeChainImpl.invokeNext(InterceptorManager.java:822)
at com.sun.ejb.containers.interceptors.InterceptorManager.intercept(InterceptorManager.java:369)
at com.sun.ejb.containers.BaseContainer.__intercept(BaseContainer.java:4667)
at com.sun.ejb.containers.BaseContainer.intercept(BaseContainer.java:4655)
at com.sun.ejb.containers.EJBLocalObjectInvocationHandler.invoke(EJBLocalObjectInvocationHandler.java:212)
at com.sun.ejb.containers.EJBLocalObjectInvocationHandlerDelegate.invoke(EJBLocalObjectInvocationHandlerDelegate.java:88)
at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy307.persist(Unknown Source)
at SessBeanPack.__EJB31_Generated__provaBean__Intf____Bean__.persist(Unknown Source)
at managedbeans.Neo4jMBean.createUser(Neo4jMBean.java:122)
at managedbeans.UserMBean.createUser(UserMBean.java:130)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
at javax.el.ELUtil.invokeMethod(ELUtil.java:326)
at javax.el.BeanELResolver.invoke(BeanELResolver.java:536)
at javax.el.CompositeELResolver.invoke(CompositeELResolver.java:256)
at com.sun.el.parser.AstValue.invoke(AstValue.java:269)
at com.sun.el.MethodExpressionImpl.invoke(MethodExpressionImpl.java:304)
at com.sun.faces.facelets.el.TagMethodExpression.invoke(TagMethodExpression.java:105)
at javax.faces.component.MethodBindingMethodExpressionAdapter.invoke(MethodBindingMethodExpressionAdapter.java:87)
at com.sun.faces.application.ActionListenerImpl.processAction(ActionListenerImpl.java:102)
at javax.faces.component.UICommand.broadcast(UICommand.java:315)
at javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot.broadcastEvents(UIViewRoot.java:790)
at javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot.processApplication(UIViewRoot.java:1282)
at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.InvokeApplicationPhase.execute(InvokeApplicationPhase.java:81)
at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:101)
at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.execute(LifecycleImpl.java:198)
at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:646)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.service(StandardWrapper.java:1682)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:318)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:160)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.doInvoke(StandardPipeline.java:734)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.invoke(StandardPipeline.java:673)
at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebPipeline.invoke(WebPipeline.java:99)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:174)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.doService(CoyoteAdapter.java:357)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:260)
at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper.service(ContainerMapper.java:188)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.runService(HttpHandler.java:191)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.doHandle(HttpHandler.java:168)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpServerFilter.handleRead(HttpServerFilter.java:189)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.ExecutorResolver$9.execute(ExecutorResolver.java:119)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeFilter(DefaultFilterChain.java:288)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeChainPart(DefaultFilterChain.java:206)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.execute(DefaultFilterChain.java:136)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.process(DefaultFilterChain.java:114)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.ProcessorExecutor.execute(ProcessorExecutor.java:77)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.nio.transport.TCPNIOTransport.fireIOEvent(TCPNIOTransport.java:838)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.AbstractIOStrategy.fireIOEvent(AbstractIOStrategy.java:113)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.run0(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:115)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.access$100(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:55)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy$WorkerThreadRunnable.run(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:135)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.doWork(AbstractThreadPool.java:564)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.run(AbstractThreadPool.java:544)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

This is the code of the Entity NewTable

```
    package entity;
    import java.io.Serializable;
    import javax.persistence.Basic;
    import javax.persistence.Column;
    import javax.persistence.Entity;
    import javax.persistence.Id;
    import javax.persistence.NamedQueries;
    import javax.persistence.NamedQuery;
    import javax.persistence.Table;
    import javax.validation.constraints.NotNull;
    import javax.validation.constraints.Size;
    import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlRootElement;
    @Entity
    @Table(name = "new_table")
    @XmlRootElement
    @NamedQueries({
@NamedQuery(name = "NewTable.findAll", query = "SELECT n FROM NewTable n"),
@NamedQuery(name = "NewTable.findByA", query = "SELECT n FROM NewTable n WHERE n.a = :a"),
@NamedQuery(name = "NewTable.findByB", query = "SELECT n FROM NewTable n WHERE n.b = :b")})

public class NewTable implements Serializable {

private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
@Id
@Basic(optional = false)
@NotNull
@Column(name = "a")
private Integer a;
@Basic(optional = false)
@NotNull
@Size(min = 1, max = 45)
@Column(name = "b")
private String b;

public NewTable() {
}

public NewTable(Integer a) {
    this.a = a;
}

public NewTable(Integer a, String b) {
    this.a = a;
    this.b = b;
}

public Integer getA() {
    return a;
}

public void setA(Integer a) {
    this.a = a;
}

public String getB() {
    return b;
}

public void setB(String b) {
    this.b = b;
}

@Override
public int hashCode() {
    int hash = 0;
    hash += (a != null ? a.hashCode() : 0);
    return hash;
}

@Override
public boolean equals(Object object) {
    // TODO: Warning - this method won't work in the case the id fields are not set
    if (!(object instanceof NewTable)) {
        return false;
    }
    NewTable other = (NewTable) object;
    if ((this.a == null && other.a != null) || (this.a != null && !this.a.equals(other.a))) {
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}

@Override
public String toString() {
    return "entity.NewTable[ a=" + a + " ]";
}}
```

This is the code of the session bean which manages the entity NewTable

```
    package SessBeanPack;
    import java.util.logging.Level;
    import java.util.logging.Logger;
    import javax.ejb.Stateless;
    import javax.ejb.LocalBean;
    import javax.persistence.EntityManager;
    import javax.persistence.EntityManagerFactory;
    import javax.persistence.Persistence;
    @Stateless
    @LocalBean
    public class provaBean {
EntityManagerFactory emf = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("EnterpriseApplication2-ejbPU");
public void persist(Object object) {
    EntityManager em = emf.createEntityManager();
    try {
        em.getTransaction().begin();
        em.persist(object);
        em.getTransaction().commit();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Logger.getLogger(getClass().getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, "exception caught", e);
        em.getTransaction().rollback();
    } finally {
        em.close();
    }
}}
```

I get that sequence of errors when i call the method persist() of the Session Bean provaBean

```
    NewTable N=new NewTable(7, password);
    provaBean.persist(N);
```

I haven't found yet a solution for fixing this problem, because most of the times people suggest to modify the persistence.xml file, because it's not written correctly probably.
My case is different because, as you can see below, the persistence.xml is filled as it should be (the class NewTable is declared as suggested by many users --->  < class > NameOfTheClass < / class > )

```
<persistence version="2.0" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_0.xsd">
 <persistence-unit name="EnterpriseApplication2-ejbPU" transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL">
  <provider>org.eclipse.persistence.jpa.PersistenceProvider</provider><non-jta-data-source>RDBforTes</non-jta-data-source>
  <class>entity.Autore</class>
  <class>entity.CanzoneUtente</class>
  <class>entity.Utente</class>
  <class>entity.TagCanzone</class>
  <class>entity.TagAlbum</class>
  <class>entity.Album</class>
  <class>entity.TagAutore</class>
  <class>entity.Tag</class>
  <class>entity.Canzone</class>
  <class>entity.NewTable</class>
  <exclude-unlisted-classes>false</exclude-unlisted-classes>
  <properties>
   <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.url" value="jdbc:mysql://127.0.0.1:3306/tesinatbd"/>
   <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.password" value="mypassword"/>
   <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.driver" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"/>
   <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.user" value="root"/>
  </properties>
 </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

I really don't know how to solve this problem; i tried some solutions suggested by users, founded here on stackoverflow, but i haven't found a working one.

So i created a new question, and i hope someone will help me.

Thanks for the answer

Comment: I get the same error when i try to use the persist() method of all the other classes showed in the persistence.xml

Comment: This is probably not the source of your problem, but `non-jta-data-source` and the `javax.persistence.jdbc` properties you're using are not meant to be used together. Maybe that halts the initialization before the classes are processed? Have you looked for any errors or warnings before the exception?

Comment: Could you explain the meaning of non-jta-data-source and javax.persistence.jdbc? Why shouldn't they used togheter? I don't know anything about and i want to understand as much as possible
This is the only warning i get (when i do "Clean and Build" project):

Comment: 'warning: Supported source version 'RELEASE_6' from annotation processor 'org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.modelgen.CanonicalModelProcessor' less than -source '1.8'
Note: Creating static metadata factory ...
Note: Optional file was not found: META-INF/orm.xml continuing with generation.
Note: Optional file was not found: META-INF/eclipselink-orm.xml continuing with generation.
Note: Optional file was not found: META-INF/orm.xml continuing with generation.
Note: Optional file was not found: META-INF/eclipselink-orm.xml continuing with generation.'

Comment: Note: Some input files use unchecked or unsafe operations.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:unchecked for details.
1 warning'

Comment: The (non-)jta-data-source is configured on the server, accessible by name. It provides the JPA with access to the database in a way that you don't have to keep the ip,user,password and db name inside your project. When you specify them with those properties, you're telling the JPA to create it's own connections. You can only use one of those methods at a time. JTA is another abstraction technology to control when you commit or discard changes to your data. Available by default in Glassfish and TomEE, but not in Tomcat.